# sum of array fields using jquery closest

Tags: jquery, arrays, closest

I need some help solving this problem,

i have dynamically created div,

```
<div class='items'>
     Item 1 <input type='text' class='subprice'  name='item[]'> [X]
     Item 2 <input type='text' class='subprice'  name='item[]'> [X]
    <input type='text' class='subprice'  name='subtotal'>
</div>

<div class='items'>
    Item 1 <input type='text' class='subprice'  name='item[]'> [X]
    Item 2 <input type='text' class='subprice'  name='item[]'> [X]
    Item 3 <input type='text' class='subprice'  name='item[]'> [X]
    <input type='text' class='subprice'  name='subtotal'>
</div>
```

how am i able to get the total array value of item[] by using `.closest` and display it to the subtotal text field.. note that class items is dynamically created, therefore it can be created multiple times.

i tried

```
var i = $(.items).closest();
var arr =  i.find('[name="item[]"]');
```

so `arr` should contain the sum of item[] within the nearest class `items`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you dont  need `.closest()` in `$(.items).closest();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `subtotal` field should be array and try like,

```
$('.items').each(function(){
   var items = $(this).find('[name="item[]"]'),
       total=0; 
   items.each(function(){
       total+=Number(this.value);
   });
   $(this).find('[name="subtotal[]"]').val(total);
});
```

Snippet,

```js
$(function() {
  function subTotal(items) {
    items.each(function() {
      var items = $(this).find('[name="item[]"]'),
        total = 0;
      items.each(function() {
        total += Number(this.value);
      });
      $(this).find('[name="subtotal[]"]').val(total);
    });
  }
  subTotal($('.items'));
  $('.delete').on('click', function() {
    items = $(this).closest('.items');
    $(this).closest('.item').remove();
    subTotal(items);
  });
});
```

```css
.delete {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='items'>
  <div class="item">Item 1 <input type='text' class='subprice' name='item[]' value="8"><span class="delete">Delete</span></div>
  <div class="item">Item 2 <input type='text' value="5" class='subprice' name='item[]'><span class="delete">Delete</span></div>
  <input type='text' class='subprice' name='subtotal[]'>
</div>
<div class='items'>
  <div class="item">Item 1 <input type='text' class='subprice' name='item[]' value="8"><span class="delete">Delete</span></div>
  <div class="item"> Item 2 <input type='text' class='subprice' name='item[]' value="55"><span class="delete">Delete</span></div>
  <div class="item">Item 3 <input type='text' class='subprice' name='item[]' value="14"><span class="delete">Delete</span></div>
  <input type='text' class='subprice' name='subtotal[]'>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way i can deleted a row and re compute for the subtotal? the computation works now as it is returning the correct subtotals based on your snippets. my problem now is when i delete one row it doesnt re compute the subtotals.

Comment: Make a function and paste my code in it. Now call the function when you delete a row.

Comment: there is no delete row functionality in your function?

Comment: @neilfurry you didn't try delete and not added in your question. As per your initial problem you was just needed to add item's subtotal and I answered with the same. So you have to add the `$('.items').each` loop functionality in your delete event. I have updated my snippet with delete functionality.

Comment: Welcome @neilfurry .

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can start at the subtotals and get its siblings (in the example setup, no further filtering is needed):

```
$('[name=subtotal]').val(function(){
    return $(this).siblings().toArray().reduce(function(sum,inp){return sum + +inp.value;} ,0);
});
```

```js
$('[name=subtotal]').val(function(){
 return $(this).siblings().toArray().reduce(function(sum,inp){return sum + +inp.value;} ,0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='items'>
     Item 1 <input value=10 type='text' class='subprice'  name='item[]'>
     Item 2 <input value=11 type='text' class='subprice'  name='item[]'>
    <input type='text' class='subprice'  name='subtotal'>
</div>

<div class='items'>
    Item 1 <input value = 5 type='text' class='subprice'  name='item[]'>
    Item 2 <input value = 6 type='text' class='subprice'  name='item[]'>
    Item 3 <input value = 7 type='text' class='subprice'  name='item[]'>
    <input type='text' class='subprice'  name='subtotal'>
</div>
```